# What is the classical counterpart of ultra-cold atoms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, chaos-theory, cold-atoms

I'm studying quantum chaos in ultra-cold atoms. However, quantum chaos denotes the quantum mechanics of classically chaotic systems and it is not clear to me what is the classical counterpart of models like the Bose-Hubbard model, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every quantum-mechanical model has an immediate, unique classical counterpart.

That said, classical counterparts for the Bose-Hubbard model have been proposed, for instance, in Kolovsky's [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.03413), "Bose-Hubbard Hamiltonian: Quantum Chaos approach", and in Graefe's [thesis](http://aleph.physik.uni-kl.de/~korsch/diss/diss_graefe.pdf), "Quantum-Classical Correspondence for a Bose-Hubbard dimer and its non-Hermitian generalization".